# entity referenced to multiple instances by instert into the database with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

I'll insert a blog into my database with Entity Framework and a ASP.NET MVC application. If I will to add the entity to the context, I ve got this error on the last line of my code below.

> **`InvalidOperationException`:** An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of `IEntityChangeTracker`.

Here is my code:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateBlog(BlogViewModel vm)
    {
        try
        {
            _blogService.Insert(new Blog()
            {
               Titel = vm.Titel,
               Beschrijving = vm.Beschrijving,
               Content = (vm.Actie.ToLower() == "publiceer" ? true : false),
               Verwijderd = false,
               Auteur = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
           });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Blog));
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IBlogService blog)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        _blogService = blog;
    }
}

public class BlogService : IBlogService
{
    public void Insert(Blog blog)
    {
        _blogRepo.Insert(blog);
        _blogRepo.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class BlogRepo : GenericRepo<Blog>
{
    public override Blog Insert(Blog blog)
    {
        context.Entry(blog.Auteur).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        return dbSet.Add(blog); // --> on this line
    }
}
```

Could you find me the problem I've made? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your userManager and your blogService share the same dbContext. If not then the user is holded by 2 contexts.

Comment: You should have one and only one instance of your context per request. Either define it as a private field on your controller and manually inject it into the `UserManager` and `BlogService` instances, or use a dependency injection container to manage the lifetime and injection.

Comment: @tschmit007: No there is only one `dbContext` each time.

Comment: how can we be sure of that, how do you instanciate your controller (constructor) and/or inject your dependencies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your entity model looks like:

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // etc
    public string Titel { get; set; }

    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }

    public bool Content { get; set; }

    public bool Verwijderd { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Auteur { get; set; }
}
```

Why don't you just add AuteurId property to your entity class. In this way you will avoid additional query where you getting user entity (`UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())`).

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // etc
    public string Titel { get; set; }

    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }

    public bool Content { get; set; }

    public bool Verwijderd { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Auteur")]
    public string AuteurId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Auteur { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your action code will be like

```
_blogService.Insert(new Blog()
{
   Titel = vm.Titel,
   Beschrijving = vm.Beschrijving,
   Content = (vm.Actie.ToLower() == "publiceer" ? true : false),
   Verwijderd = false,
   AuteurId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
});
```

Comment: Yes. Because it's `ApplicationUser Auteur` that's tracked twice. Once by the UserManger's context and once by the repository's context when the blog is added.